# Plesk: PHP handler successfully registered but not available in Plesk

Tags: plesk

I wanted PHP 5.4.45 for one of my web spaces so I've downloaded and installed it ([following these instructions](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=70669.htm)) but although I've registered it and had a success message, it doesn't show in the dropdown within the Plesk panel.

I've run the following command:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --add -displayname 5.4.45 -path /usr/local/php5445/bin/php-cgi -phpini /usr/local/lib/php.ini -type fastcgi -id 5.4.45-lsiv6
```

I had the following message:

```
The new PHP handler with the id "5.4.45-lsiv6" was successfully registered
```

However it's not available in the dropdown box.

[image]

How can I get this new version to show within Plesk?

Answer (score 0):

Run

/usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --reread

and check again.